# Dokuwiki cannot support filename which contains uppercase letter(s)?

Tags: dokuwiki

There

[Dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki#), an excellent wiki tool, but it fails to support filename which contains uppercase letter(s) when upload attachment.

[image]

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DokuWiki aims to be as portable as possible. This means it allows you to move your existing wiki data between operating systems and file systems without problems. To achieve this (and cope with different file systems being case sensitive or not) it enforces some naming standards (all files being lower case being one of them).

When you upload the file through DokuWiki's media manager it will automatically be renamed to comply to the naming standards used within DokuWiki. If you upload via the file system you have to make sure your files comply manually.

Comment: Where are those file naming standards?